# JSP Custom Taglib

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

I'm running in Liferay 7 but I am trying to create a custom tag but keep getting this error when I try to run it.

```
[fileinstall-/Development/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/osgi/war][org_apache_felix_fileinstall:103] Error while starting bundle: webbundle:file:/Development/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/osgi/war/digital-lexicon-portlet-7.0.0.1.war?Bundle-SymbolicName=digital-lexicon-portlet&Web-ContextPath=/digital-lexicon-portlet 
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: digital-lexicon-portlet [587]_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.swabunga.spell.engine; resolution:="optional"_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.swabunga.spell.event; resolution:="optional"_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: net.fortuna.ical4j.model; resolution:="optional"_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: net.fortuna.ical4j.model.property; resolution:="optional"_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.axis.tools.ant.wsdl; resolution:="optional"_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.bsf; resolution:="optional"_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel; resolution:="optional"_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel; resolution:="optional"_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.portals.bridges.common; resolution:="optional"_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.portals.bridges.struts; resolution:="optional"_  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.extender; filter:="(&(osgi.extender=jsp.taglib)(uri=/WEB-INF/tld/tile.tld))"_ [Sanitized]
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:429)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:402)
at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1252)
at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1224)
at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:512)
at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:361)
at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:313)
```

I've followed tutorials and my structure looks like this:

```
docroot/WEB-INF/src
  com.lexicon
    - TileTag.java
  com.liferay.docs.lexicon.portlet
    - LexiconPortlet.java
```

My `TileTag.java` looks like this:

```
package com.liferay.docs.lexicon.portlet;

import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TileTag extends SimpleTagSupport {

  public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
    JspWriter out = getJspContext().getOut();
    out.println("Hello Custom Tag!");
  }
}
```

My `docroot/WEB-INF/tld/tile.tld` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.2//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd">

<taglib>
  <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
  <jsp-version>2.0</jsp-version>
  <short-name>UI Tile</short-name>
  <tag>
    <name>tile</name>
    <tag-class>com.liferay.docs.lexicon.portlet.TileTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>empty</body-content>
  </tag>
```

In my `view.jsp` I have:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tld/tile.tld" prefix="lex" %>
<lex:tile />
```

Comment: whatever jar is providing the package net.fortuna.ical4j.model is not in your osgi's classpath

Comment: Forgive me, I'm very new with Java but I went into OSGi Framework run configuration and made sure all bundles were checked and even validated them and added any required bundles.

Comment: @JoshChristensen The errors appears to be not from the tag but from some other class using the missing import.Check your bundle import dependencies for any missing classes.

Comment: The manifest has nothing in it, `Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: `

Comment: When I remove the line in my view `<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tld/tile.tld" prefix="lex" %>` and republish it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I've run into almost the exact same situation.    I'm porting a JBoss Portal portlet project that produces a war file, and works perfectly, to a Liferay Portal / Wildfly environment.  When I remove the <%@taglib descriptor from my JSP file, the BundleException goes away (which shows that that is what is causing the problem), but I lose the taglib functionality in the JSP, which is the whole point of including it in the first place.